# scipy.optimize.curve_fit a definite integral function with scipy.integrate.quad

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy, curve-fitting

If I have a function that the independent variable is the upper limit of an definite integral of a mathematical model. This mathematical model has the parameters I want to do regression.
This mathematical model is nonlinear and can be complicated.

1. How can I solve this?
2. if the output of my function is then be processed， can it be curve_fit?

There is a simplified case

```
import scipy.optimize as sp
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np
number = 100

def f(x,a,b,c):
    return 500*a*x+b*c

def curvefit(d,a,b,c):
    return quad(f,0,d,args=(a,b,c))[0]

x_linear = np.linspace(0.001,0.006,number)
y_linear = 23.33*x_linear + 0.02*(np.random.random(number)-0.5)
parameter = sp.curve_fit(curvefit,x_linear,y_linear)
```

x and y _linear are number I made up.

d in curvefit() is now x_linear that is a list, and is the upper limit in quad().

The error shows ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I know quad() requires upper limit to be float.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is raised inside the function `scipy.integrate.quad` because d is a `numpy.array` and not a scalar. The function given to `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` take the independent variable (`x_linear` in your case) as first argument.

The quick and dirty fix is to modify curvefit to compute the definite integral for each value in d:

```
def curvefit(xs,a,b,c):
    return [quad(f,0,x,args=(a,b,c))[0] for x in xs]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It reports an error of TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable now. I have separate the codes alone and it did work well, but with the original line, scipy.optimize.curve_fit(curvefit,x_linear,y_linear), it shows this error.

Comment: Can you update the question with the code you actually run ?

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment, I made a silly mistake. It works well. Thank you!