# Is there a good way to combine scipy curve_fit and scipy solve_ivp?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, differential-equations

I've been wondering if there is a way to use something like scipys curve_fit function to determine the arguments of an initial value problem of ode's for which one could use scipy's solve_ivp.

```
def lotkavolterra(t, z, a, b, c, d):
    x, y = z
    return [(a*x - b*x*y), (-c*y + d*x*y)]
```

**Concretely:**
Image for example, you know that your data follow the Lotka-Volterra equations(s.above), but due to noise you can't figure out the coefficients(a,b,c,d). The time points and the initial values are known exactly. How could one obtain the missing coefficients efficiently?

**Note** There has been already some discussion about the usage of curve_fit in integrate_quad in this thread [scipy.optimize.curve_fit a definite integral function with scipy.integrate.quad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49526859/scipy-optimize-curve-fit-a-definite-integral-function-with-scipy-integrate-quad)